# The Unicorn Mystery - Solidity fails to decode valid UTF-8 encoded bytes

Tags: solidity, string, bytes

The Ethereum Foundation has the Unicorn token to encourage donations, and the unicorn emoji is represented by three bytes. How in the world did they do that?

I know that Solidity supports unicode escapes, so something like `\u2934` in a string is displayed in Mist as ⤴ . But what about something like the puppy emoji ?

One would think the escape sequence would be `\u1F436`, but instead Mist just shows a character that isn't what I want, presumably whatever emoji has the encoding `\u1F43`.

So then I tried with two unicode points: `\uD83D\uDC36`. Mist didn't show anything.

The following commit makes me think this is impossible, because it seems to me like the `for loop` has `i` iterating through four characters, or two bytes for each escape sequence:
https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/666/commits/aa4593cab3d60468e5ea4318012c5252ebbc7d13
And as noted, unicode points don't seem to work, or at least aren't displayed in Mist (yet Mist shows the Unicorn emoji).

How in the world do I support an emoji consisting of 3+ bytes?

**EDIT:**

`0xcaff` found a bug in the way that Solidity decodes UTF-8 encoded bytes.

I've filed the issue on GitHub: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2383
If someone has a fix, the bounty is theirs. Otherwise it will go to `0xcaff`.

**EDIT II:**

The issue has been closed, UTF-8 validation has been fixed (or at least improved) and changes have been merged: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/2386

Now you can use emojis in Solidity with something like:

```
string public constant working = hex"F09F90B6";
```

Using the UTF-8 encoded bytes that can be generated from sites like https://mothereff.in/utf-8.

Woohoo!

Comment: Oh, and the Unicorn docs aren't very helpful either: https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TokenTrader/wiki/UNI-%E2%80%90-Unicorn-%F0%9F%A6%84#the-token-contract-source-code

Comment: Where exactly are you seeing the unicorn icons? I've only ever seen them as embedded `.png` files, but perhaps you've seen them elsewhere :)

Comment: Ok, sorry, you're saying in Mist...

Comment: Which was added in this commit: https://github.com/ethereum/ethereum-org/commit/7d63760acd89b0d11e080693bc84e531943b25c1

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking it might be [this](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereum-org/commit/7d63760acd89b0d11e080693bc84e531943b25c1#diff-0f7f02c213f61721866733c89e021e90R36)...

Comment: ...but that translates to a different icon. (URL too long to paste here, but copy it into the URL bar and it'll be rendered.) Interesting question. +1

Comment: **Update**: On top of the updates above, these days Solidity supports either injecting unicode into an ASCII (default) string using `\uNNNN` where `NNNN` is the code of the character, or a unicode string specified by `unicode""`, source: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/types.html#string-literals-and-types

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike some of the comments suggest, the unicorn symbol  (`U+1F984`) is located in the contract's symbol name. You can check this by running the following in a web3 browser's console:

```
// taken from https://github.com/flyswatter/human-standard-token-abi/blob/master/index.js
var tokenAbi = [
  {
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "name",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "type": "function"
  },
  {
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "name": "_spender",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "name": "_value",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "name": "approve",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "success",
        "type": "bool"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "type": "function"
  },
  {
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "totalSupply",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "type": "function"
  },
  {
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "name": "_from",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "name": "_to",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "name": "_value",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "name": "transferFrom",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "success",
        "type": "bool"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "type": "function"
  },
  {
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "decimals",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "type": "uint8"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "type": "function"
  },
  {
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "version",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "type": "function"
  },
  {
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "name": "_owner",
        "type": "address"
      }
    ],
    "name": "balanceOf",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "balance",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "type": "function"
  },
  {
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [],
    "name": "symbol",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "type": "function"
  },
  {
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "name": "_to",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "name": "_value",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "name": "transfer",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "success",
        "type": "bool"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "type": "function"
  },
  {
    "constant": false,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "name": "_spender",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "name": "_value",
        "type": "uint256"
      },
      {
        "name": "_extraData",
        "type": "bytes"
      }
    ],
    "name": "approveAndCall",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "success",
        "type": "bool"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "type": "function"
  },
  {
    "constant": true,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "name": "_owner",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "name": "_spender",
        "type": "address"
      }
    ],
    "name": "allowance",
    "outputs": [
      {
        "name": "remaining",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "payable": false,
    "type": "function"
  },
  {
    "inputs": [
      {
        "name": "_initialAmount",
        "type": "uint256"
      },
      {
        "name": "_tokenName",
        "type": "string"
      },
      {
        "name": "_decimalUnits",
        "type": "uint8"
      },
      {
        "name": "_tokenSymbol",
        "type": "string"
      }
    ],
    "type": "constructor"
  },
  {
    "payable": false,
    "type": "fallback"
  },
  {
    "anonymous": false,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "indexed": true,
        "name": "_from",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "indexed": true,
        "name": "_to",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "indexed": false,
        "name": "_value",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Transfer",
    "type": "event"
  },
  {
    "anonymous": false,
    "inputs": [
      {
        "indexed": true,
        "name": "_owner",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "indexed": true,
        "name": "_spender",
        "type": "address"
      },
      {
        "indexed": false,
        "name": "_value",
        "type": "uint256"
      }
    ],
    "name": "Approval",
    "type": "event"
  },
];

// get symbol
var tokenContract = web3.eth.contract(tokenAbi);
var instance = tokenContract.at("0x89205a3a3b2a69de6dbf7f01ed13b2108b2c43e7");
instance.symbol.call((thing1, thing2) => global.symbol = thing2);
```

Let's investigate this string:

```
symbol.length // Output: 2
symbol.codePointAt(0) // Output: 129412 (0x1F984)
symbol.split("").map(char => char.charCodeAt(0)); // Output: [55358, 56708]
```

Let's talk about UTF-8, the character encoding mist uses. According to [FileFormat.info](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/utf8.htm):

> UTF-8 is a compromise character encoding that can be as compact as ASCII (if the file is just plain English text) but can also contain any unicode characters (with some increase in file size).
>
> UTF stands for Unicode Transformation Format. The '8' means it uses 8-bit blocks to represent a character. The number of blocks needed to represent a character varies from 1 to 4.

What we have here is unicode code point: 29412 (0x1F984). [It looks like solidity only supports encoding codepoints between 0x0000 (0) and FFFF (65535) using the `\uNNNN` syntax.](https://github.com/axic/solidity/blob/aa4593cab3d60468e5ea4318012c5252ebbc7d13/libsolidity/parsing/Scanner.cpp#L198) Typically languages allow encoding with over this amount using surrogate characters. Solidity doesn't seem to.

No worries, we should be able to just put the hex encoding of the correct unicode sequence and the correct text should be rendered.

Contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract EmojiCon {
    string public constant working = hex"F09FA684";
    string public constant broken = "\uD83D\uDC36";
}
```

Test (truffle):

```
var EmojiCon = artifacts.require("./EmojiCon.sol");

contract('EmojiCon', function(accounts) {
  it("should match the string", async function() {
    const instance = await EmojiCon.deployed();
    const workingString = await instance.working.call();
    console.log(workingString);
  });

  it("shouldn't match the string", async function() {
    const instance = await EmojiCon.deployed();
    const brokenString = await instance.broken.call();
    console.log(brokenString);
  });
});
```

Unfortunately it won't compile:

```
Compiling ./contracts/EmojiCon.sol...
Compiling ./contracts/Migrations.sol...

/home/vm/ethereum/unicode/contracts/EmojiCon.sol:4:35: : Type literal_string (contains invalid UTF-8 sequence at position 3) is not implicitly convertible to
expected type string memory.
        string public constant working = hex"F09FA68421";
                                         ^-------------^
Compiliation failed. See above.
```

The error comes from [here](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/8eead553aff1ec30c3d1b15ae9b2929b887ede49/libsolidity/ast/Types.cpp#L1071). It seems the validator chooses an incorrect value for `count` and stops too early. ([isolation](https://ideone.com/sO8fwT) ([original](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/8f9839c6ed7e7083eed32dd0ef9c6f8278d2a2f8/libdevcore/UTF8.cpp))). This seems to be a bug/missing feature in solidity. Hope this helps.

Comment: Excellent work! I'm filing a new issue with Solidity on GitHub. The bounty will remain up for grabs if anyone can offer an actual fix, but otherwise I shall give it to you for finding what I agree to be the root cause.

Comment: Alright, I've filed an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/2383. Anyone who can actually publish a fix will get the bounty, otherwise it will go to 0xcaff.

Answer (score 1):

You can use keyword `unicode""`
Example: `string public saudacao = unicode"Olá sou uma variável ";`